# MySQL One-way compare two tables with no primary key

Tags: mysql, comparison

I have two tables. They don't have primary keys or unique columns. They have the same number of columns.

```
+---------------+  
|    table_1    |  
+---------------+  
| a | b | c | d |  
+---+---+---+---+  
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  
+---+---+---+---+  
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |  
+---+---+---+---+ 

+---------------+
|    table_2    |
+---------------+
| a | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

I want to get the data from table_2 that is not present in table_1 by comparing all fields.

My query is this below but it is returning all records not present on both tables.

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d
    FROM table_1 as t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d
    FROM table_2 as t2
)  t
GROUP BY a, b, c, d
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY a

+----------------+
|        t       |
+----------------+
| id | a | b | c |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
+----+---+---+---+
```

My desired result is this.

```
+----------------+
|        t       |
+----------------+
| id | a | b | c |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
+----+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the set of records which are unique to each of the two tables.  One way to achieve this is to `UNION` together two `LEFT JOIN` queries which obtain the records not common between the tables.

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c AND t1.d = t2.d
WHERE t2.a IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d
FROM table_2 t2
LEFT JOIN table_1 t1
    ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c AND t1.d = t2.d
WHERE t1.a IS NULL
```

Follow the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9269e/5)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get the rows that doesnot exist in the second that you can use such query

```
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE NOT 

      EXIST (SELECT * FROM B WHERE
      A.field1 = B.field1
```